What was the female equivalent of πάππας in Ancient Greek?
The Pope is a major world religious figure whose name happens to derive from πάππας. There has been a lot of interest, both as far back as medieval Europe and contemporaneously, about the possibility of a Pope who was not male, which naturally leads one to wonder about the correct Greek term.
The reason I ask this is because it seems as if the terms μήτηρ, μᾱ́τηρ, and μᾱ́ταρ are rather equivalents of πατήρ (cognate of pater), whereas πάππας seems to be a little different, i.e. it is basically a diminutive, "daddy." So there must be a term that was used as "mommy" that would have been its equivalent. What was that term?

FWIW, Pope Joan is called a Πάπισσα in Modern Greek.

As addendum to Federico Poloni's remark, most languages opted for a feminine version of the male title. Pope Joan is known as: Fr. papesse Jeanne, Ger. Päpstin Johanna, It. Papessa Giovanna. I have tried to find a Greek text from around the time the legend originated in the 13th century, but have not had any luck so far.

Μάμμη is the female equivalent of πάππας.

So, a female Pope would have to be a Mame, I guess? Or a Mome. Interesting.

Was there ever an equivalent with another vowel, corresponding to one of those somewhat different pronunciations of the baseline word for "mother," like μήμμη?

I don't think there is;  μάμμα seems the only alternative. The linked page gives information from other dictionaries as well.
